# How to make multiple variables readonly in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, it is idiomatic to write

```
$_ = '2021-04-09 10:23:42';
my ($year, $month, $day) = m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;
```

How can I use this with [Readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly) ? Trying `Readonly::Array`

```
Readonly::Array my ($year, $month, $day) => m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;
```

results in

```
Type of arg 1 to Readonly::Array must be array (not list) at rdonly.pl line 4, near "m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;"
```

Trying `Readonly::Scalar`

```
Readonly::Scalar my ($year, $month, $day) => m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;
++$year;
die $year unless $year == 2022;
```

results in

```
1 at rdonly.pl line 9.
```

($year is not read-only and has an incorrect value)

Answer (score 3):

**Interface 1**

```perl
Readonly::ManyScalars my ($year, $month, $day) => [ /^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\z/ ]
   or die("Invalid input\n");
```

```perl
while ( Readonly::ManyScalars my ($k, $v) => [ each %h ] ) {
   ...
}
```

Implementation:

```perl
use Readonly qw( );

sub Readonly::ManyScalars {
   my $vals = pop(@_);
   for (0..$#_) {
      Readonly::Scalar $_[ $_ ] => $vals->[ $_ ];
   }

   # As similar to list assignment as we can.
   return wantarray ? @_ : 0+@$vals;
}
```

This version has the advantage of being similar to the existing Readonly subs. Note that you need to create an array from the assigned values (e.g. by wrapping the expression in square brackets as shown above).

---

**Interface 2**

```perl
(ro my $year, ro my $month, ro my $day) = /^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\z/
   or die("Invalid input\n");
```

```perl
while ( (ro my $k, ro my $v) = each(%h) ) {
   ...
}
```

Implementation:

```perl
use Readonly        qw( );
use Variable::Magic qw( wizard cast );

my $wiz = wizard(
   data => sub { [ 0, $_[1] ] },
   set => sub {
      Readonly::Scalar(${ $_[1][1] }, ${ $_[0] });
      $_[1][0] = 1;
   },
   free => sub {
      Readonly::Scalar(${ $_[1][1] }, undef) if !$_[1][0];
   },
);

sub ro(\$) :lvalue { cast(my $proxy, $wiz, $_[0]); $proxy }
```

This version has the advantage that not all the variables have to be read-only, and you do stuff like `(ro my $x, undef, ro my $z) = ...` rather than using dummy vars.

Comment: Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a clean way of doing this. However, combining [`refaliasing`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Assigning-to-References) (or [`Data::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) on older Perls) and `Readonly` does the trick, although it looks quite dirty:

```
use Readonly;

$_ = '2021-04-09 10:23:42';

\(my @ymd) = (\my $year, \my $month, \my $day);
my @matching = m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;
map { Readonly::Scalar $ymd[$_] => $matching[$_] } 0 .. $#ymd;

print "$year/$month/$day"; # print 2021/04/09
++$year; # dies with "Modification of a read-only value attempted at tmp.pl line ..."
```

The result is pretty similar as what you wanted. In particular, the content of `@ymd` is also read-only, which means that you won't have the surprise of discovering that `$year` was modified through `@ymd`.

Using [`List::MoreUtils::pairwise`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#pairwise-BLOCK-ARRAY1-ARRAY2) allows to replace

```
map { Readonly::Scalar $ymd[$_] => $matching[$_] } 0 .. $#ymd;
```

With

```
pairwise { Readonly::Scalar $a => $b } @ymd, @matching;
```

Which looks a bit nicer.

If you'd prefer not to use the refaliasing feature, you can use `Data::Alias`: you just need to replace `\(my @ymd) = (\my $year, \my $month, \my $day);` with `alias my @ymd = my ($year, $month, $day);`

Finally, there are several ways to put that code in a `sub` in order to factorize the code a bit and improve readability. For instance:

```
$_ = '2021-04-09 10:23:42';

init_readonly(my $year, my $month, my $day,
              [m/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/]);

print "$year/$month/$day";
++$year;
die $year unless $year == 2022;

sub init_readonly {
    my $values = pop @_;
    pairwise { Readonly::Scalar $a => $b } @_, @$values;
}
```

(`Data::Alias` is not needed anymore since within a sub, `@_` contains aliases to the arguments)

Comment: Two more tips :) `my @values = @{pop @_};` makes a needless copy of every element, and `init_readonly` should return the number of values in `@values` so `init_readonly` can be used in an `if` or in `or die`.

Comment: I was about to suggest `Readonly::Scalar ${ $_->[0] } => $_->[1]
    for +zip [ \my ($year, $month, $date) ], [ m/(....)-(..)-(..)/ ];`, but I think the latest edit is quite similar.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami; that `@{pop @_}` was indeed sloppy, let's pretend I did not write that :x Good point regarding returning the number of elements in `@values`; `pairwise` kinda already does that, and your answer already showcases that, so I guess I leave mine as is before it becomes identical to yours :D (can you please not delete your comment, for future readers?)